# How to add an external audio track to a video file using VLC or FFMPEG command line

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, vlc, audio-processing

I want to add an audio.mp3 soundtrack to a soundless video.mp4 file using a bash script, what is the correct syntax of the "cvlc" "ffmpeg" command line ?

I've recorded the video with VLC and --no-audio option so there is no settings such as bit rate or encoding that can be copied from the original video.

Answer (score 34):

### Stream copy

Example to [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy), or re-mux, the video from `video.mp4` (input `0`) and the audio from `audio.mp3` (input `1`):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -codec copy -shortest out.mp4
```

This will avoid encoding and will therefore be very quick and will not affect the quality.

### Re-encode

You can tell ffmpeg what encoders to use if you do need to re-encode for size or if you need different formats than the inputs. Example to re-encode to H.264 video and AAC audio:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -codec:v libx264 \
-preset medium -crf 23 -codec:a aac -b:a 192k -shortest output.mp4
```

#### Notes:

The `-map` option allows you to specify which stream you want, for example, `-map 0:v` refers to the video stream(s) of the first input. If you do not tell ffmpeg what streams you want then it will use the default [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) which is to choose one stream per stream type. The defaults are often fine, but it is recommended to be explicit so you can get expected results.

The `-shortest` option instructs ffmpeg to end the output file when the shortest duration inputs ends.

Using a recent ffmpeg build is always recommended. Easiest method is to [download a recent ffmpeg build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), but you can also follow a [guide to compile ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

#### Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried both of your suggestions and it returns the following error message:

_Unrecognized option 'codec'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'codec'_

I've tried with 'vcodec' option and it returns :

_Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 50 >= 50_

Comment: @Jonathan You need to show your actual ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: A quick note for something that just helped me using avconv instead of ffmpeg: as avconv is actually a fork of ffmpeg, taking the first exact command line "Stream Copy" above as-is and just replacing 'ffmpeg' with 'avconv' just worked totally fine for me. HTH!

Comment: I tested this on data from youtube which streams the audio and video separately; after obtaining the source data (via httpfox and wget) the first command recombined the source files correctly.